# Is only 1-2% of the population in Myers-Briggs' INTJ category?

Tags: cognitive-science

> [INTJs are one of the rarest of the sixteen psychological types and account for approximately 1-2% of the population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTJ)

Wikipedia claims that the INTJ personality type (as defined by the [Myers-Briggs Type Indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers-Briggs_Type_Indicator)) is one of the rarest and roughly 1-2% of the population.

I have seem this claim elsewhere online before, without citations, but always similarly low ([0.8%](http://www.16personalities.com/intj-personality), [2.9%](http://www.personalitypage.com/demographics.html), [2-4%](http://www.capt.org/mbti-assessment/estimated-frequencies.htm), etc).

Is there research backing up the relative rareness of the INTJ personality type?

Comment: I think this question is answerable, but don't confuse that with the [false idea](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/give-and-take/201309/goodbye-mbti-the-fad-won-t-die) that Myers-Briggs Type is useful, repeatable, or well supported by psychology.

Comment: @Oddthinking oh I most certainly agree Myers-Briggs has its host of criticisms, much of which is valid (in my opinion).

Comment: I know every time I take a test for it I come out different. I think I did hit INTJ once.

Comment: I'm INTJ. Am I special? I don't feel special :(